# insert name attribute when check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I have a form, when the form check box is checked a name attribute should be inserted in to the check box input field with a number at the end. I made something but is not exactly working

```
when checkbox is checked it should look like this: 
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" name="my-list-item<0>" value="value">My Item<br>
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" name="my-list-item<1>" value="value">My Item<br>


<form>
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" value="value">My Item<br>
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" value="value">My Item<br>
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" value="value">My Item<br>
<input type="CHECKBOX" class="item" value="value">My Item<br>

</form>

<script>

function prepareSearchForm(form){
 var count = 0;

 $(form).children('.item').each(function(o){
   var cityDOM = document.createElement('input');

   itemDOM.name = "my-list-item<" + (count++) + ">";
   itemDOM.value = o.value;
   form.appendChild(itemDOM);
 });

}
</script>
```

Comment: An `<input />` is a self-closing tag, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: And `type=CHECKBOX` isn't valid.

Comment: input field can be closed or not either way its valid code, because the browser displays it that way

Comment: what do you mean by 'the input field'? do you have another textual input or are you talking about the checkbox itself

Comment: the check box itself

Comment: @brodster I updated my answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are going for:

```
   <form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item" onclick="checkAddress(this)" />My Item<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item" onclick="checkAddress(this)" />My Item<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item" onclick="checkAddress(this)" />My Item<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item" onclick="checkAddress(this)" />My Item<br>

</form>
<script>
    function checkAddress(checkbox)
{


    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
     var count = 0; 
     var checkboxes =  document.getElementsByClassName("item");
        for(var ii = 1; ii < checkboxes.length; ii++){
           if(checkboxes[ii].checked){
           count++; 
        }
      checkbox.name = "my-list-item" + count;
    }
    }
}
    </script>
```

If you want to add the value, just add `checkbox.value = "your value";` under the `checkbox.name`.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7teq1o9f/54/

This will output:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="item" name="my-list-item<1>" onclick="checkAddress(this)">
```

Comment: you are close, I want the name="item"  to be added,  NOT Name Field... I want the name="item" to be added to the checkbox itself

Comment: @brodster, the Javascript is the same. With the current HTML, it's changing the name attribute. If you just have the class, it will add the name :) Here is the proof: https://jsfiddle.net/7teq1o9f/38/

Comment: @brodster I've updated the answer to be exactly how you want it. :)

Comment: this works, Thanks, Can the number start with 0?  also can I move the onClick event in the script area?

Comment: @brodster yes sir, it can :) Just input whatever number in the `checkAddress(this, 0)` part. You could have it be 200 if you want :)

Comment: can I move the onClick event in the script area?

Comment: @brodster No, the `onclick` is what executes the function. It's basically a listener that triggers the function.

Comment: can I target the input field with the class or id? the number should only be applied to checked boxes in chronological order. So if checkbox 1 and ceckbox 4 is selected the number should be <0>, <1>

Comment: @brodster just updated the answer. it now works exactly how you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following in jQuery.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        'name': 'my-list-item<' + $(this).data("index") + '>'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="value" data-index="0" />My Item<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="value" data-index="1" />My Item<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="value" data-index="2" />My Item<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="value" data-index="3" />My Item<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, can the number be applied to random check boxes? lets say check box 1 and check box 5 was selected I want the check boxes to have the number applied in order 0,1 etc..

Answer (score 1):

sorry its 2am here

```
      var count = 0;
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
       $(this).attr('name',count++);
    });
```

in plain js
  this.setAttribute("name", count++);

Comment: you're attempting to append an input to a checkbox?

Comment: ...neeeed more coffee, lol its just the autocomplete in my texteditor

Comment: made some classifications in the description

Comment: hey kurt, do I need to wrap it in $(function ()

Comment: not if you use jquery, in juery $ is short hand to begin a funtction if you use js yes

Comment: I don't think this is working, I have swapped your jquery code with mine, but when i click it does not add the name attribute

Comment: This won't work because you haven't defined `count`.